# child class in scope of parent class

Tags: c++, oop, parent-child

```
class parent {
public:
    class child;  // Is this declaration inherited by parent::child class?

    int getval() const;
protected:
    parent(int val);
    int val;
};

parent::parent(int val) : val(val) {}

int parent::getval() const {
    return val;
}

class parent::child : public parent {
public:
    child();
};

parent::child::child() : parent(10) {}

int main(){
    std::cout << parent::child().getval() << std::endl;  // prints out 10 indeed!
    return 0;
}
```

No instances of `parent` allowed. `child` is in scope of `parent` and accessible as `parent::child`. This code compiles well though I have my worries it may be problematic. Since `child` inherits from `parent`, it inherits `child` declaration as well, doesn't it? And in general is it all okay to have `child` class declared in scope of `parent` class?

Comment: May I ask what you actually want to achieve with such construct?

Comment: It's legal and safe to do, but might not be the simplest solution.

Comment: For example my class `apple` inherits from `fruit`. I want it to be accessible as `fruit::apple` as `apple` alone is too confusing (umm, is `apple` a company? Confused already). `child` is in scope of `parent`. Any reasons it is a bad idea? Or what should I do instead?

Comment: It's not problematic one little bit. The parent's declaration of child is hidden in child by its injected-class-name, but that's ok, they both refer to the same type.

Comment: You can use namespaces instead (should, rather).

Comment: If your aim is to be able to call your class as: 'fruit::apple' the best way is by creating the class 'apple' in the namespace 'fruit'. If there is some attributes that you want every fruit shared then inside the namespace fruit declare a virtual class that contains these attributes e.g. basic_fruit and make every fruit type a child of this class.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `child` as a nested type of `parent` is a bad idea.

In a comment you said

> For example my class apple inherits from `fruit`. I want it to be accessible as `fruit::apple` as `apple` alone is too confusing (umm, is `apple` a company? Confused already). `child` is in scope of `parent`. Any reasons it is a bad idea? Or what should I do instead?

Now you want to add `orange` as a sub-type of `fruit`. To be consistent with `apple`, you'll have to make `orange` a nested type of `fruit` also. Every time a new sub-type of `fruit` is needed, you'll have to modify `fruit`. This violates one of the most important principles of object oriented design - [The Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

A better method to differentiate between apple the fruit and apple the company will be to use namespaces.

```
namespace products
{
   class fruit {};
   class apple : public fruit {};
}

namespace organizations
{
   class company {};
   class apple : public company {};
}
```

Now you can use `products::apple` to refer to the fruit and `organizations::apple` to refer to the company.